# Async Socket example

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm learning about socket's with C# and I implemented the client and server example from the links below:

Server - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Client - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

The example work's fine if I run it one time. So, I tryed to modify the example that I could run the client more then one times. This are the changes I did.

```
public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    string msg = string.Empty;
    while (msg != "exit")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a message:");
        msg = Console.ReadLine();

        if (msg != "exit")
            StartClient(msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I send the second message to the server, it throws an 'System.ObjectDisposedException' on the command `int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);`

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.  
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar); // This line throws an exception.

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Could anyone show me what I did wrong?

And I have a question about the server socket too. On the example, I need end the message with `<EOF>`. How can I modify the server to read all bytes (I don't know the size) without having to finish my message with `<EOF>`?

Thanks to all!

Comment: See msdn examples : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks jdweng but I implemented this examples and I'm getting this problems with this examples.

Comment: There are three methods for getting end of message 1) ASCII : add terminating character at end of data that is not part of the data 2) ASCII or Binary : Add a byte count to beginning of message 3) Use Fixed length messages.  You can have multiple different type messages like SEND 20 bytes and RECEIVE 15 bytes.  Then receive reads until end of message is found.

Comment: You cannot start client twice without closing connection.  In the client ReadCallBack the following reads next message : client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,  
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);